# Get element inside current element using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple questions inside which there are more than 1 options.

After selecting the required question element as question_element

I am unable to get the first text box inside this element. I used

```
question_element.find_elements_by_xpath("//textarea")
```

but it gives me list of all the elements with tag textarea in the whole webpage. I tried

```
question_element.find_elements_by_xpath("/textarea")
question_element.find_elements_by_xpath("./textarea")
```

but they didn't give any results. How do I get the first element with tag name textarea inside the question_element

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two variants that work for search within already found element (not within the whole page):

```
question_element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//textarea")
```

Comment: Thanks! I only found the first of these worked for me, `find_elements_by_xpath(".//textarea")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
question_element.find_elements_by_xpath("//textarea[position()=1]")
```